# Removing left factoring from Context-Free Grammar

Tags: automata, context-free, formal-grammars, parsers

I know that, removing left factoring is a simple task.
And i understand following procedure:

$S→aA | aB$
Becomes:
$S→aS'$
$S'→A|B$

Yet I'm running into problems with this particular grammar:

$S→AD|bbS|bScS|BS $
$A→aAbb | abb$
$B→aB|ba|b$
$D→cDd|cccd$

How to remove left factoring from it, I'm trying to convert  it into LL(1) grammar

Comment: What do you mean by "removing left factoring"? Left factoring is a technique that removes left recursion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194142/difference-between-left-factoring-and-left-recursion

Comment: @BearAqua The post you link to establishes a difference between left factoring and left recursion, not a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar can be abbreviated as follows:

$S \rightarrow  a^{m}b^{2m}c^{n+2}d^{n}\;|\;(a^{*}(ba|b)|bb)S\;|\;bScS; \; m,n \ge 1$

You can't factor out, for instance, the subexpressions generating the sequences of $a$'s that appear on the left. The language is not even LL($k$), let alone LL($1$).

Consider the following analogous, and simpler, example:

$S \rightarrow aS\;|\;T\; \\
T \rightarrow aTb\;|\;\varepsilon$